# Get the Key and Value from the String using NSRegularExpression in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsregularexpression

Below is my String Which I get from Qrcode:

> Address : Event :- seminar,Date & Time:- Apr 04 2018 - 2:03 PM / Aug
>   17 2018 - 1:00 AM ,Order Id :- 201807,Event location :- Pune,
>   Maharashtra, India

How to get **Order Id :- 201807** in Objective C? And before that How to check Order Id is available in my string? My previous question already deleted because I have not added code But, Here is the code which I have Implemented :

```
if ([barcode.getBarcodeType isEqualToString:@"org.iso.QRCode"]) {
    NSLog(@"Address : %@",[barcode getBarcodeData]);
    NSString *searchedString = [barcode getBarcodeData];

    NSData* data = [searchedString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *stringFromFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"Order Id :-" options:0 error:nil];

    long n = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:stringFromFile options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringFromFile length])];

    NSLog (@"Number of the match: %ld", n);

    if (n> 0) {
        NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:stringFromFile options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringFromFile length])];

        for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches)
        {
            NSString *matchText = [stringFromFile substringWithRange:[match range]];
            NSLog(@"Found String:%@\n", matchText);
        }
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"No match found in file %@", searchedString);
}
```

In above code I get **Order Id :-** but I need Order Id with value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the fact that you want number in your regex. Currently, your Regex is not really a "regex", it's just a a simple rangeOfString. Possible pattern: `Order Id :- (\\d*)`.

Comment: In that now I need only number like `201807`

Comment: With my regex pattern, it's just `NSString *matchText = [stringFromFile substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];` to modify. You might want to learn about regex and group (there are plenty of online testers)

Comment: Ok thanks both of you. It's working. @Vinaykrishnan That is my first question How to check that id and value exist or not?

Comment: i hint if it doesn't exist, your n will be 0. And also you can put an additional check if the matches array contains an elements.

Comment: ok that n condition I have already added. I will add additional contains condition. Thank you man.

Comment: Also if the string only contains "Order Id :-" with out value substringWithRange: will return blank.

Comment: Understood  thanks.